# Date Issue transferring data from Oracle To Salesforce

Tags: salesforce, mule

I am facing a strange issue transferring data from ORacle to Salesforce. I am using Mule as the solution for integration.A date with following value "10/19/2005 11:59:00 PM" appears as 10/20/2005 on Salesforce. Can you help identify what is the cause of this issue. 
the only possible solution to this issue available with me is to recreate a date from the received value without the time parameters. but i dont think that this is a correct.

kindly advise.

regards
Santosh

Comment: What's the integration user's timezone vs. the organization's timezone? Is the target field of Date or DateTime type? Can you inspect the value in SF database (make a SOQL query, don't view them in browser / in a report. Finally - what if you'll try with "10/19/2005T23:59:00Z"?

Comment: The object type is Date. i am looking for a way to validate the time zone.

Comment: if the target field is of type Date you'll see only the Date part and no Time. And it might be perfectly legal to "round" the value to full day. Can you flip the field type in Salesforce to DateTime?